# Trying to return randomized integers using an array

Tags: c

```
int die[5] = { 0 };

int roll_die(void)  
{  
    return rand(1, 6) % 6 + 1;  
}


for (index = 0; index < 5; (++index) && (i++))  
    {  
        roll_die(die, 5); //tried as &die as well, but same problem  
        printf("die[%d]:  %d\n\n", i, die[index]);  
    }
```

prints die[1] - die[5] will 0 values instead of randomly generated integers between 1 and 6

Comment: i dont think you understand what you are doing.. you are not giving any value to the array, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Read [ask], provide a [mcve]. And read the documentation of the functions you use. Also pay heed to compiler warnings (**enable them!**) and errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to replace `roll_die(die, 5);` by `die[index] = roll_die(die, 5);` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int roll_die()
{
    return rand() % 6 + 1;
}

int main() {
    int die[5] = { 0 }, index;

    for (index = 0; index < 5; (++index))
    {
        die[index] = roll_die();   
        printf("die[%d]:  %d\n\n",index, die[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you used `rand` wrong, didnt used the returned value, and the way you called the function was wrong.

hope that helps.

p.s.
its better also to call
`srand(time(NULL));`
once in the start

Answer (score 0):

Rollling a Dice with JShell (Java)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2CIxn0C1qo

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function that takes no parameters (void) with parameters.
I'm talking about this line right here: `roll_die(die, 5);`

The way you declared and defined the function roll_die is so that it just returns a random number `int roll_die(void)`

Whatever value this function return must be assigned to someting like @t.elazari mentioned:

`die[index] = roll_die();`

Here you are saying that the value of the array `die` in the index `index` (`die[index]`) will equal whatever `roll_die()` returns.

Follow his example, I'm just giving you a short explanation of why you did it wrong.

The function that he mentioned (`srand(time(NULL));`) goes inside the main function, anywhere as long as it is BEFORE the `for` loop. This function changes the `seed` of the `rand` to be the current time. If you don't do this, your `rand` function will return the same values always, they are random but their seed is always the same.